# Hard DP prob pseudocode algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

So this is the question:

There’s an actor doing fan meeting who is trying to do free hugs to his fans lined up in a line. He starts at position 0 and there are fans to his right and left. Their position is depicted by both neg and pos number like -3, 5, etc. The ‘utility’ (economics) his fan gains from the hug starts at certain number, say 10, and decreases by 1 per 1 distance he walks. The actor wants to find an algorithm to maximize the utility his fans gain.

For example, the maximum utility the fans at pos 2, 4, 6 with initial utility of 10 can get is 8 + 6 + 4.

The number of fans N can be up to 100 and initial utility M can be up to 10000 (can’t be negative). The fans’ positions are between -10000 to 10000.

Please help solve this q in pseudocode given the initial utility, number of fans and fans’ position.

I somehow cant think of ways to work it through.

Answer (score 1):

dp[r][l][b][i] = max utility you can get by having visited r as the rightmost fan, l as the leftmost fan, b is a boolean saying if you are at position of rightmost fan or left, and i is the remaining utility. The amount of possible states are 100 * 100 * 2 * 10000 = 200000000, should be doable to solve in less than a second.

Pseudocode: Separate fans in 2: the ones < 0 and the ones > 0.

```
solve(left, right, atRight, utility):
    if left < 0 or right > totalFans or utility <= 0:
        return 0
    if dp[left][right][atRight][utility] != None:
        return dp[left][right][atRight][utility]        

    if atRight == true:
        dp[left][right][atRight][utility] = max(solve(left, right + 1, true, utility - distance(right, right + 1)), solve(left + 1, right, false, utility - distance(right, left + 1))) + utility
    else:
        dp[left][right][atRight][utility] = max(solve(left + 1, right, false, utility - distance(left, left + 1)), solve(left, right + 1, true, utility - distance(right + 1, left))) + utility

return dp[left][right][atRight][utility]



answer = max(solve(0, 1, true, initialUtility - distance(0, firstFan at dist > 0)), solve(1, 0, false, initialUtility - distance(0, firstFan at dist < 0)))
```

You basically try all possibilities, your state is where you are, the rightmost fan you already hugged, the leftmost fan you already hugged and the remaining utility. If leftmost fan is 10, that means you already hugged closest fan to 0 that was at pos < 0, second, third, 4th... up to 10th.

Comment: Would u take care to explain it a bit more? I somehow still do not get your idea?